# Gigabit connection not working properly on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, ethernet

I there, so i should be receiving `200Mbps` internet connection speed, but i am only getting `95 Mbps` on www.speedtest.net . So i was checking my `eth0` interface and it seems to support Gigabit connections and my ethernet cable is a `cat5`.

when i run `sudo ethtool eth0`

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

do this settings look ok? should i be enabling something to get something closer to `200 Mbps` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
[...]
Speed: 100Mb/s
```

The "link partner" is the switch/router/modem to which your computer is connected. Possible explanations for the above diagnosis:

- The link partner doesn't support Gigabit Ethernet (or has it disabled for some reason, e. g. to save power).
- The signal-to-noise ratio on the connection cable(s) is too low because they lack proper electro-magnetic shielding. This may lead to the link partners agreeing on a lower link speed to maintain a reliable connection. If this is the case, replace the cable (and any other potential connection equipment like wall plugs) by one with at least CAT5e or CAT6 shielding that isn't broken.

Comment: weird... so my laptop supports it then?

Comment: The output of `ethtool` is pretty literal even without specific knowledge of technical terms. Both "supported [and] advertised link modes" list "1000baseT/Full". So, yes, your Ethernet adapter does support Gigabit link speed.